# integrate a (OSM) nearby search functionality into my GitHub project page - my approach

Tags: javascript, html, github, github-pages

i have a question:  well  is it possible to integrate a (OSM) nearby search functionality into my GitHub project page, that said: GitHub Pages, which hosts project pages, primarily serves static content, so we won't be able to  directly run server-side code like PHP to interact with APIs.

However, there is hope:  we can still achieve a similar functionality by using client-side languages like JavaScript to make requests to the Overpass API and display the results on our GitHub project page. i  guess that there some options would be like so: could this be a high-level overview of how we could approach it:

first of all see the intened osm - nearby-search that runs on the overpass-Turbo.eu -API

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,::lon,::lat,amenity,name,"addr:postcode","addr:city","addr:street","addr:housenumber","contact:website",website,"contact:email")]
[timeout:600];

area[name="München"];
nwr(area)[name="Marienplatz"];
nwr["amenity"="school"](around:10000);
out center;
```

it gives back the results:

```
@id @type   @lon    @lat    amenity name    addr:postcode   addr:city   addr:street addr:housenumber    contact:website website contact:email
312793352   node    11.5815046  48.1322045  school  Schulverbund München    80469   München Kohlstraße  5       https://www.schulverbund.de/    
703266518   node    11.5746643  48.1387135  school  EAM School of International Business                    https://eam-muenchen.com/       
1096318121  node    11.5827303  48.1368214  school  Otto-Falckenberg-Schule 80539   München Stollbergstraße 7a      https://www.otto-falckenberg-schule.de/ 
1096318127  node    11.5822067  48.1376239  school  Otto-Falckenberg-Schule 80539   München Falckenbergstraße   2       https://www.otto-falckenberg-schule.de/ 
1142514805  node    11.5665710  48.1353750  school  Evangelisches Bildungszentrum   80331   München Herzog-Wilhelm-Straße   24  https://www.stadtakademie-muenchen.de/      stadtakademie.muenchen@elkb.de
1576527684  node    11.5728245  48.1336093  school  Theresia-Gerhardinger-Grundschule am Anger                      https://gs-am-anger.de/ 
1576528339  node    11.5721671  48.1333479  school  Theresia-Gerhardinger-Gymnasium am Anger                        https://www.tggaa.de/   
2493656150  node    11.5814603  48.1366835  school  Förderschule an der Herrnstraße 80539   München Herrnstraße 21      https://stadt.muenchen.de/service/info/sonderpaedagogisches-foerderzentrum-muenchen-mitte-2-herrnstr-21/1060084/    
2654727020  node    11.5812823  48.1365482  school  Grundschule an der Herrnstraße  80539   München Herrnstraße 21
```

well - i want to add such a serarch retrival on my github-page:

well i think i need to work on the **following parts:**

**HTML/CSS**: Create a structure and styling for our project page, including any elements needed for displaying the search results.

**JavaScript**: now we would have to write JavaScript code to handle user interactions, make requests to the Overpass API, and dynamically update the page with the retrieved data. we can use libraries like Leaflet.js for mapping functionalities if needed.

**GitHub Pages Integration:** we ought to add the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files to our GitHub repository and configure GitHub Pages to serve them as our project page.

well - i think we should go like this:   - see a simplified example of how we might implement the JavaScript part to perform a **nearby search** using Overpass API:

```
html
Copy code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nearby Schools Search</title>
    <!-- Include any CSS files here -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Nearby Schools</h1>
    <div id="schoolList"></div>

    <script>
        // Function to perform nearby search
        function nearbySchoolsSearch() {
            var url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter';
            var data = '[out:json][timeout:25];(node["amenity"="school"](around:10000,48.1351,11.5820););out;';

            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Display search results
                var schools = data.elements;
                var schoolList = document.getElementById('schoolList');
                schoolList.innerHTML = '<ul>';
                schools.forEach(school => {
                    schoolList.innerHTML += '<li>' + school.tags.name + '</li>';
                });
                schoolList.innerHTML += '</ul>';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }

        // Call the nearbySchoolsSearch function when the page loads
        window.onload = nearbySchoolsSearch;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do you say:  well i think this code creates a simple HTML page with a heading and a  element where the search results will be displayed.  The JavaScript code uses the Fetch API to make a request to the Overpass API, retrieves the nearby schools,
and dynamically updates the page with the results

Well  - i look forward to  hear from you

regards